# AWS - cannot open asp.net web app after a successful publishing

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, amazon-ec2, publish

After spending a few hours on struggling with establishing the connection between Visual Studio publish and AWS EC2. I finally published the ASP.NET app to EC2 but I got this `'server not found'` message and obviously I cannot open up the web app at all.

I have this api.app.com domain put into a IIS site's bindings as Host Name and my EC2 instance public IP into the site's IIS bindings as IP address. Also, the port is 80 (better to set to something else?).

I got this api.app.com domain from AWS Route 53 and set up Resource Record Set for it - it is a A type (IPv4) with my EC2 public IP.

So what does this 'server not found' message suggest? And what could be the reasons for my issue? Thanks.

I highly suspect my registered domain name - api.app.com isn't visual on the internet at all. How do I test this? Sorry, my networking knowledge is close to 0.

:(

EDIT: This time, I published the ASP.NET app to app.com (which is the domain I registered, api.app.com is a subdomain I created) and the message is `'The connection has timed out'`, so it is different to `'server not found'`. What does it suggest here?

Answer (score 0):

If you suspect a domain issue.  Try deploying to the IP address instead.